# Pyspark turn a list to a dictionary in a specific column

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have a spark dataframe that looks like this in json;

```
{
  "site_id": "ABC",
  "region": "Texas",
  "areas": [
    {
      "Carbon": [
        "ABB",
        "ABD",
        "ABE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "site_name": "ABC"
}
```

and I need to turn "areas" column to this;

```
"areas": 
  [
    {
        "area_name": "Carbon",
        "pls": [
         {
             "pl_name": "ABB"
         },
         {
             "pl_name": "ABD"
         },  
         {
             "pl_name": "ABE"
         }
       ]
    }

]
```

I already did df.collect() and manipulated the dictionary directly, but that created some complexity. Is there a way to do this directly in the dataframe itself?

Edit:
Here is the input schema

```
|-- site_id: string
|-- region: string
|-- site_name: string
|-- areas: array
|    |-- element: map
|    |    |-- keyType: string
|    |    |-- valueType: array
|    |    |    |-- element: string
```

in the output schema, the goal is to have the valueType also a dictionary. I actually save the data to a dynamodb table so the output should like the example I provided when scanned from the table.

Comment: Can you describe your input and output schema? `areas` is `MapType` or `StructType`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing and producing JSON is not Spark's strength as far as my understanding. The easiest approach (that is not flattening then grouping by then collecting then pivoting etc) is using UDF. I completely understand UDF is not as fast as built-in Spark transformation, but if your data scale is not that big then it shouldn't be a problem.

```py
def transform_json(arr):
    r = []
    for e in arr:
        for k in e.keys():
            r.append({
                'area_name': k,
                'pls': [{'pl_name': i} for i in e[k]]
            })
    return r

(df
    .withColumn('areas', F.udf(
        transform_json,
        T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
            T.StructField('area_name', T.StringType()),
            T.StructField('pls', T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
                T.StructField('pl_name', T.StringType())
            ]))),
        ])
        ))('areas')
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

# Output
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |areas                                                             |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{Carbon, [{ABB}, {ABD}, {ABE}]}, {Oxygen, [{ABB}, {ABD}, {ABE}]}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+

# Schema
# root
#  |-- areas: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- area_name: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- pls: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- pl_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This worked great! Is there a considerable disadvantage of using UDF on a relatively large dataset? I'm kind of new to Spark actually I have been mostly working with Pandas up until now.

Comment: UDF is technically slower than Spark built-in functions. There is a very long answer to that, but search for Catalyst and Tungsten and you will understand more.

Comment: Just one more thing, why is the area_name returns null? I tried to use it with the map type but still returns null.

Comment: I forgot that in your expected output, `areas`  is an array of **objects**, not an array of maps. In Spark, a map's value has to have a strict type, while in your case, you have two keys `area_name` has type String, and `pls` has type Array. The bottom line is, I updated the code to make it returns a struct type instead of map type